# Phonegap app closing problem

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap with Android.I have a sound playing repeatedly with a timer.If I close the app the sound continues to play.Is there a app closing handler or something I could use to make the sound stop when the app exits.

I am using a Samsung Captivate(Galaxy S).If I press the back button the sound stops when the app exits.But if I press the home button then the sound just goes on forever when the app exits.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the backbutton and stop the music playing and then close the app.
It's however not possible (as far as i know) to catch the close event.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/29494136/Android-Back-Button-Handler
Here is how to do that.